# Looking for method to remove spaces on sides, change all letters to small with first letter as capital letter

Tags: java, regex, string, methods

I have been trying for a while to make a method which takes an user input and changes it so that potential spaces infront and after the text should be removed. I tried .trim() but doesnt seem to work on input strings with two words. also I didnt manage to make both first and second word have the first letter as Capital.

If user inputs the following string I want all separate words to have all small letters except for the first in the word. e.g: Long Jump
so if user inputs:

```
"LONG JuMP"
```

or

```
"  LoNg  JUMP  "
```

change it to

```
"Long Jump"
```

---

```
private String normalisera(String s) {
    return s.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

I tried the method above but didnt work with two words, only if the input was one. It should work with both

Answer (score 3):

To remove all spaces extra spaces you can do something like this

```
string = string.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

The above code will call trim to get rid of the spaces at the start and end, then use regex to replace everything that has 2 or more spaces with a single space.

To capitalize the first word, if you're using Apache's `commons-lang`, you can use `WordUtils.capitalizeFully`. Otherwise, you'll need to use a homebrewed solution.

Simply iterate through the String, and if the current character is a space, mark the next character to be uppercased. Otherwise, make it lowercase.

Comment: As java Strings are immutable you would want to use a char array for doing the capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

Split your problems into smaller ones:

You need to be able to:

- iterate over all words and ignore all whitespaces (you can use Scanner#next for that)
- edit single word into new form (create helper method like `String changeWord(String){...}`)
- create new String which will collect edited versions of each word (you can use StringBuilder or better StringJoiner with delimiter set as one space)

So your general solution can look something like:

```
public static String changeWord(String word) {
    //code similar to your current solution
}

public static String changeText(String text) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");// space will be delimiter
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(text)){
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sj.add(changeWord(sc.next()));
        }
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Strings are immutable and you cannot make in place changes you need to store it in a separate variable and then do your manipulations like this:

```
String s = " some output ";
String sTrimmed = s.trim();
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(sTrimmed);
```

Change your code like this for the rest of your code as well.